# Unable to change volume size on WD My Passport Wireless

Tags: mac, partition, external-disk, disk-volume

I have been trying to partion my WD My Passport External harddrive that has already got data on it. All of the guides I see on the internet tell you to resize the current volume to do so. I don't have the tab to do this in disk utilities.
[image: This is the image to accompany my reply to a comment]

Comment: Are you sure you are clicking on the name of the volume and not on the existing partition? In Disk Utility, you should be clicking on the item that says "2 TB WD My Passport..." (with the size at the beginning obviously dependent on the size of your drive). This item will be against the left edge of the window, and should not be indented. It will, however, have at least one item below it that is indented. See [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/yHgV1YN.png). You need to click on the volume, not a partition, to add or modify partitions.

Comment: I have tried to modify the partions by clicking through the volume but it says that the partion can't be modified, also it doesn't have the button to drag the partion sizes, I have added a screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Disk Utility you should see something like this

[image: partition]

Select the external disk (called Hitachi in this example)

Click on the partition you want to work on, and resize it